# Using Hazelcast for both Spring Session and 2 Level Cache (LC2) with Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hazelcast, spring-session, spring-cache

So I want to use Hazelcast in my web application for both 2 level caching (hibernate layer) and spring session, the setup is very simple I want to be able to use NearCache configurations with a server running on the network.

I first ran into a compatibility problem recent version of Hazelcast 4.* is not yet supported in spring session, so I was happy to use the supported version: 3.12.6...
below is my hazelcast-client.xml and I have properly configured it to be used by ***spring.hazelcast.config=file://...*** when I start my application the Hazelcast instance is not created, so I decided well I should create the ***ClientConfig*** and ***HazelcastInstance*** beans myself using the code below:

```
@Bean()
ClientConfig clientConfig() throws IOException{
    try(final InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("proper-path/hazelcast-client.xml"))){
      com.hazelcast.client.config.XmlClientConfigBuilder builder = new com.hazelcast.client.config.XmlClientConfigBuilder(stream);
      return builder.build();
    }
  }
@Bean()
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(final ClientConfig clientConfig){
    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
}
```

Now i have a problem, I can't add the code below so I can use it with sessions:

```
final MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
            .setName(HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
            .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

hazelcastInstance.getConfig().getMapConfig(HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME)
        .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
        .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));
```

hazelcast-client.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
                  http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.12.xsd">
    <group>
        <name>GroupName</name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </group>
    <instance-name>${application.container.name}</instance-name>
    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.shuffle.member.list">true</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.timeout">60000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.heartbeat.interval">5000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.event.thread.count">5</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.event.queue.capacity">1000000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.client.invocation.timeout.seconds">120</property>
    </properties>
    <client-labels>
        <label>web-app</label>
        <label>${application.container.name}</label>
    </client-labels>
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>127.0.0.1</address>
        </cluster-members>
        <outbound-ports>
            <ports>5801</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <smart-routing>true</smart-routing>
        <redo-operation>true</redo-operation>
        <connection-timeout>60000</connection-timeout>
        <connection-attempt-period>3000</connection-attempt-period>
        <connection-attempt-limit>2</connection-attempt-limit>
        <socket-options>
            <tcp-no-delay>false</tcp-no-delay>
            <keep-alive>true</keep-alive>
            <reuse-address>true</reuse-address>
            <linger-seconds>3</linger-seconds>
            <buffer-size>128</buffer-size>
        </socket-options>
    </network>
    <executor-pool-size>40</executor-pool-size>
    <native-memory enabled="false" allocator-type="POOLED">
        <size unit="MEGABYTES" value="128"/>
        <min-block-size>1</min-block-size>
        <page-size>1</page-size>
        <metadata-space-percentage>40.5</metadata-space-percentage>
    </native-memory>
    <load-balancer type="random"/>
    <flake-id-generator name="default">
        <prefetch-count>100</prefetch-count>
        <prefetch-validity-millis>600000</prefetch-validity-millis>
    </flake-id-generator>
    <connection-strategy async-start="true" reconnect-mode="ASYNC">
        <connection-retry enabled="true">
            <initial-backoff-millis>2000</initial-backoff-millis>
            <max-backoff-millis>60000</max-backoff-millis>
            <multiplier>3</multiplier>
            <fail-on-max-backoff>true</fail-on-max-backoff>
            <jitter>0.5</jitter>
        </connection-retry>
    </connection-strategy>

   </hazelcast-client>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the map on the server side, which means you need to have some of the Spring classes on member's classpath. But keep in mind that you need this configuration only when `HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository#findByIndexNameAndIndexValue` is used.

Also in client mode, do not forget to deploy necessary classes and enable user code deployment for members. Otherwise session updates will fail:

```
// member
config.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig().setEnabled(true)
      .setClassCacheMode(UserCodeDeploymentConfig.ClassCacheMode.ETERNAL);

// client
clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig().setEnabled(true).addClass(Session.class)
            .addClass(MapSession.class).addClass(SessionUpdateEntryProcessor.class);
```

But I recommend to include spring-session-hazelcast on member's cp rather than user code deployment. This will satisfy both of the needs above.

Finally, if `hazelcast-client.xml` exists in one of the known paths in your project (e.g. under `resources/`), the client will be created with this configuration. You do not need to create ClientConfig bean in that case.

Comment: "You need to configure the map on the server side"??? This got me confused I have one Web Application, before I start the application I started the cluster batch file that comes with hazelcast zip file, I configured the hazelcast.xml to my settings and then started it.

Comment: The zip file does not contain any of these spring-session classes as it's maintained by Spring. And I really don't get what exactly got you confused: configure the map in hazelcast.xml - or programmatically, then start the member.

Comment: FYI: They introduce Hazelcast 4.0 support with v2.4.0 release. Currently, Oct 28th is the expected release date.

Comment: even though your answer was not exact you set me on the right path I think I have a better understanding on what I have to do

Comment: I was thinking the answer was highlighting all the necessary stuff. Sorry about that. If you elaborate the non-exact part, may be I will try to make clear next time. Happy to see it helped anyway.